# How to increment active cell in excel vba 4 steps?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code which will enter data into a sheet. So once the data is entered, the form is reset and new data items can  be entered. But this new data items should be gone to sheet in such a way that each time there is change in position. As in figure below, when i enter data using the form, it will get filled from `B1` to `D4`. Now I require the cell to be selected for next entry is `F1`. ie, next set of data has to be filled from `F1` to `H4`.

[image: See Image]

I tried `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select` but it is taking me to cell `T2` then next time to `U2` and all

Here is my code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim p As Long
Dim j As Integer
Dim erow As Long
Dim b As Integer
'erow = Sheet3.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
a = number
For p = 2 To number + 1

    Cells(p, 2) = Controls("txtBox" & p - 1).Text
    Cells(p, 3) = Controls("txtBox" & p + number - 1).Text
   Cells(p, 4) = Controls("txtBox" & p + number + number - 1).Text

Next p


'Cells(3, i) = TextBox1.Value
'Cells(4, i) = TextBox2.Value
'Cells(5, i) = TextBox3.Value
'Cells(3, i + 1) = TextBox4.Value
'Cells(3, i + 1) = TextBox4.Value

Call resetForm
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select

End Sub
```

> Text boxes are dynamically created

My form looks like this :

[image]

What has to be modified?

Comment: You are missing some other parts of your code which are important. Like, what is `ActiveCell` before you use `ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select`. In fact, you should avoid using `ActiveCell` and `Select` all together

Comment: initially i will set B3 as active cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest something like the following:
It finds the last used column in row 2 and moves 2 right to get the first cell for the new data block. Note that for the first data block we need to move only one right.

This example adds some sample data to the next empty block:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet3

    Dim LastCol As Long
    LastCol = ws.Cells(2, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'get the last used column in row 2

    Dim FirstCellToWrite As Range
    If LastCol = 1 Then
        Set FirstCellToWrite = ws.Cells(2, LastCol + 1) 'first data block is different
    Else
        Set FirstCellToWrite = ws.Cells(2, LastCol + 2)
    End If

    'write example values
    FirstCellToWrite.Value = 1
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(0, 1).Value = 2
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(0, 2).Value = 3
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(1, 0).Value = 4
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(1, 1).Value = 5
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(1, 2).Value = 6
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(2, 0).Value = 7
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(2, 1).Value = 8
    FirstCellToWrite.Offset(2, 2).Value = 9
End Sub
```

Comment: but everytime the number of textboxes can vary...data will vary

Comment: Of course you need to adjust this to use the data of your text boxes. This is just an example. I left some work for you, this is meant to point you into the direction of a solution.

Comment: this is updating the same data everywhere

Comment: actually user will enter 1 set of data.. then the next set entered should come in next location

Comment: As I said there is some work for you. This is just an example how to find the next empty location. You need to change the code to fill in your data from the text boxes. This is your work to do now.

Comment: no i changed the codes... what i am getting is.. the form data is added to first set... then the second set of values replaces the first set

Comment: Not if your sheet looks **exactly** as the screenshot in your question: then please add your actual code additionally to the existing code at the end of your original question.

Comment: its working....thank you..small mistake from my part happened...now its rectified and working,..thank you