# How to display/remove row items which are 4 cells apart in listbox VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list box, which requires to display items from a row. Here each item is 4 cells apart. So I tried to display it,but it displays the items along with the bank cells. I tried to offset, but no use.

[image]

So here, the list box should display these items A,B,C without spaces also deletion should occur properly.

My code :

```
Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Range("B1").Select
End Sub
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
If TextBox1.Value = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Please Add something")

Else
    ActiveCell = TextBox1.Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "a"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "b"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "c"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.Value = "d"

    ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 1).Select

    End If

'For i = 3 To ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row Step 2       

'Next i
  'ListBox1.RowSource = "Sheet3!1:1" & Range("A" & Column.Count).End(xlUp).Column


  Dim lCol As Long

'Determine last column
lCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Dim rngSource As Range
'Set range source data to be included in listbox
Set rngSource = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(1, lCol))

'Populate listbox with range source data
'ListBox1.List = rngSource.Cells.Value
Call resetForm

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

try the following. You might want to clear before adding. This assumes a form control listbox.

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

Dim myListBox As Object
Set myListBox = ActiveSheet.Shapes("List Box 1").OLEFormat.Object

myListBox.AddItem Range("B1")
myListBox.AddItem Range("F1")
myListBox.AddItem Range("J1")

End Sub
```

Or find the last column in the row, create a range from B1 to this column and loop this adding items:

```
With ActiveSheet

    Dim loopRange As Range

    Set loopRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)

End With

Dim currentCell As Range

For Each currentCell In loopRange

    myListBox.AddItem currentCell

Next currentCell
```

[image: Data should be coming in this listbox]

Comment: this one is working..but there is an issue... it is, first it will add a, then a,b then a,b,c...finally the list box will be like, a,a,b,a,b,c

Comment: does this occur just with the bottom one? And is this actually a listbox? And is it a form control?

Comment: the thing is that, i have a userform, it accepts data and add it to these cells. below the text box there is a listbox where i can remove items if there is a wrong entry made.

Comment: It is difficult for me to visualize, can you add images to your post? I thought you just wanted to loop the range and add the non blank items. If it is a listbox then AddItem will not concatenate subsequent entries as it will have moved onto the next item.  So I am guessing there is something else going on maybe in relation to the TextBox where entries might somehow be concatenated (that is a guess).

Comment: Is the method similar to your post here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49359593/how-to-add-listbox-items-to-a-column-in-vba

Comment: it is similar to this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49315496/how-to-increment-active-cell-in-excel-vba-4-steps