# How to add listbox items to a column in vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 list boxes like in image.So when the listbox 2 is finalised and I click 'OK', the data in listbox2 should be added to range A2 to down. Data is populated in listbox 1 using `.AddItem` 
.
[image]

I tried like this :

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub BTN_moveAllLeft_Click()

    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.ListBox2.List(iCtr)
    Next iCtr

    Me.ListBox2.Clear
End Sub
Private Sub BTN_moveAllRight_Click()

    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCtr)
    Next iCtr

    Me.ListBox1.Clear
End Sub
Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedLeft_Click()

    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox1.AddItem Me.ListBox2.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.ListBox2.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.ListBox2.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox2.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr

End Sub
Private Sub BTN_MoveSelectedRight_Click()

    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox2.AddItem Me.ListBox1.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.ListBox1.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.ListBox1.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr

End Sub

Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
Dim lngLastRow As Long
    Dim lngCol As Long
    Dim lngIndex As Long

    lngLastRow = Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    lngCol = 4
    For lngIndex = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
        If ListBox1.Selected(lngIndex) Then
            Cells(lngLastRow, lngCol) = ListBox2.List(lngIndex)
            lngCol = lngCol + 1
        End If
    Next
End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Dim iCtr As Long

    With Me.ListBox1
        For iCtr = 1 To 10
            .AddItem "This is a test" & iCtr
        Next iCtr
    End With

    Me.ListBox1.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti
    Me.ListBox2.MultiSelect = fmMultiSelectMulti

End Sub
```

Comment: where in your code are you moving the items from `ListBox1` to `ListBox2` ?

Comment: wait i will update full code

Comment: yea i have updated my full code

Comment: You may have a typo in your `cmdOK_Click`, you are using ListBox1.ListCount in the for loop. Is that how you wanted it to be?

Comment: Actually i need to store what ever is coming in listbox2 into a sheet column once ok button is pressed

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to populate data from Listbox2 in Range A2 and down once button `OK` is pressed, try this:

```
Private Sub cmdOK_Click()
   Dim lngLastRow As Long
   Dim lngCol As Long
   Dim lngIndex As Long

   For lngIndex = 0 To ListBox2.ListCount - 1
      Cells(lngIndex + 2, 1).Value = ListBox2.List(lngIndex)
   Next
End Sub
```